Is this sql code susceptible to SQL injection?
I have a MariaDb/PHP application used for searching biological names (Latin/Swedish) from a large scientific database.
The only user textual input is to provide a (partial) name in a textfield, read by PHP and inserted in a SQL query (abbreviated):
    Select ... from Database.table x WHERE Condition AND MATCH 
    (x.scientific_name) AGAINST ('"full name"' IN BOOLEAN 
    MODE) ;

or
    Select ... from Database.table x WHERE Condition
    AND x.scientific_name LIKE '%partial_name%' AND 
    !isnull(x.scientific_name ;

These queries return 0 or more results from the database.table, defined by:
scientific_name varchar(255)
I am presently not using parameterized queries (do I have to?)
(MariaDb ver. 11.6.2, PHP ver. 8.2, Debian 12 server with Apache2)
EDIT: PHP code:
//User input:
<input type='search' name='srcfield' id='srcfield' value='' size='45' maxlength='55' autofocus placeholder="Sök efter organism/taxon... (fågelnamn)" style='font-size:14px;background-color: #DCF7E7;'
oninput='fonblur1(srcfield)'>

//returns srcfield to a PHP var => $safein1 via js:
function fonblur1() {
var x = document.getElementById("srcfield");
...
}

//A large amount of various non-text input is used to build the dynamic SQL, e.g:

         <input type="checkbox"  id="cb02" name ="exakt2" onclick="" >
        <label for="cb02">search exact/whole name</label></span>


//Dynamic SQL (untranslated code):
$sqlsrc = "SELECT f.`TaxonId`,f.`Taxonkategori`,f.`Vetenskapligt_namn0`, 
f.`URL_till_taxoninformation` AS `URL_till_taxoninformation`, 
d.Familj AS Familj, d.Slakte AS Slakte, 
d.TaxonId AS TaxonId2, t.taxid, 1 AS accept , 'nosyn' AS syn
concat(d.Rike,' -› ', d.Fylum,' -› ',IFNULL(d.Klass, '~')) AS grupp, 
FROM namndata.ftextsrc f 
JOIN namndata.taxonid0 t using (Taxonkategori)
JOIN namndata.taxon0_T d USING (TaxonId) 
WHERE f.`Vetenskapligt_namn0` LIKE '%" . $safein1 . "%'  " .
 " AND d.TaxonStatus='Accepterat' AND d.".$roww2['Taxonkategori'] ." = '".$roww2['Vetenskapligt_namn']."' 
 " . $TxIdf . "    
order by grupp, d.radnr, f.`Vetenskapligt_namn0` LIMIT 0,2500;";  



// Actual code, sent to MariaDb:
SELECT f.`TaxonId`,f.`Taxonkategori`,f.`Vetenskapligt_namn0`, 
f.`URL_till_taxoninformation` AS `URL_till_taxoninformation`, 
d.Familj AS Familj, d.Slakte AS Slakte, 'nosyn' AS syn, 
d.TaxonId AS TaxonId2, t.taxid, 1 AS accept, concat(d.Rike,' -› ', d.Fylum,' -› ',IFNULL(d.Klass, '~')) AS grupp 
FROM namndata.ftextsrc f JOIN namndata.taxonid0 t using (Taxonkategori) 
JOIN namndata.taxon0_T d USING (TaxonId) 
WHERE MATCH (f.`Vetenskapligt_namn0`) AGAINST ('"carnivora"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND d.TaxonStatus='Accepterat' AND d.Fylum = 'Chordata' order by grupp, d.radnr, f.`Vetenskapligt_namn0` LIMIT 0,2500;



Yes, your code is susceptible to SQL injection.
Anywhere dynamic SQL is built using string concatenation with variables (that are influenceable) is always at risk for SQL injection. It's a pretty hard and fast rule to never do that. - j-d
You need to instead generate the parameters dynamically, see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/279895 for an example. The column names will have to be injected. You should use a whitelist for this which is validated on the server-side, not the client. - charlieface
